# RestClient from Spring 6.1 and mocking

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I use RestClient instead of RestTemplate. Has anyone mocked RestClient in a nice manner using Mockito in tests?

It's a chain api, therefore I end up with multiple when().thenReturn() statements to mock a single get() or post().

Comment: Just don't mock but uae the `MockRestTestService` from Spring Test instead. Or if you really want to mock, set the mocking to return new mock when a method is being called, saves you a lot of intermediate `when().thenReturn()`.